# Sending html and css mails to gmail with Swift Mailer

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I have some basic html and some css but for some reason gmail puts **3D** infornt the 'text/css'

Code sample

```
$message = "
            <style type='text/css'>
              #main {border:1px solid red;}
            </style>

              <div id='main'>some text</div>
";
```

But when I view the original send to the gmail

```
<style type=3D'text/css'>
```

and maybe thats why the mail is not styled. I am using the swift mailer

// also in html

```
<div id=3D'main'>
```

// swift mailer

```
    $type = $message->getHeaders()->get('Content-Type');
    $type->setValue('text/html');
    $type->setParameter('charset', 'utf-8');
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable#Quoted-printable_encoding <-- This looks useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know gmail doesnt support style tag in head or in body. I use style attributes for elements when sending email.

Comment: yes this is true but also you need further lines to make every thing work, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

to let swift mailer send message in HTML format, even for gmail , because swift mailer escape html tags to its represented characters , so you need to write these lines this way:

```
$message = (new Swift_Message('Message Subject HERE '))
        ->setFrom(array('sender email' => 'Sender Name')) // can be $_POST['email'] etc...
        ->setTo(array('reciever email' => 'Receiver Name')) // your email / multiple supported.
        ->setEncoder( new Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_PlainContentEncoder('8bit'))
        ->setBody($template, "text/html");
```

after that every thing should work fine 
the trick here is to till swift mailer to use Swift mailler MimeType class and point to the  correct encoding . you can check here for more information [link here](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#setting-the-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Swift Mailer is trying to escape " to \".
You have to use setEncoder() before setBody():

```
$message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding());
$message->setBody($body, "text/html");
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I added `$message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding());` and when I `print_r` the message after sending from on my server, the HTML part is shown as `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` and the equal signs appear as desired (i.e., just =). However, when receiving this message, the HTML part has been changed to `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` and the equal signs show as `=3D`. Using Swiftmail version Swift-5.4.3. Tried multiple receiving hosts and multiple receiving mail clients, all with the same result.

Comment: As mentioned, the `$message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding());` modification did not fix the issue for me. However, `$message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::getBase64Encoding());` encodes the HTML part as `base64` data and this comes through untouched on the other end. This was particularly important to me as not only is the HTML now rendering properly, but I am also signing my messages with an `S/MIME` signature and the received modified message caused the signature to be invalid. Now, the signature remains valid as the message is unmodified on the receiving end.

Comment: static calling did not work and even it is not in current version 6.1 documentation, use normal new keyword instantiation instead